# Thunderbird: addon to show "Received from"

Tags: email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there some Addon for Thunderbird, which will display the "Received from" information from the email header? Ideally, I would like to be able to see the whole route where the email has traveled before it was delivered to me. But most importantly, I am interested in the originating IP

Comment: You do know you can see this in the source of the e-mail? You can click a mail and then under view choose "Message source" (or type Ctrl+U). If you want to display the headers above the email it will take up a lot of space. But there are a lot of add-ons who can do this. Not sure if [view-headers-toggle-button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/thunderbird/addon/view-headers-toggle-button/) still works. Or [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/thunderbird/addon/toggle-headers/?src=search). But did you already search for them yourself?

Comment: I did search but I could not find any. I know that the "Received From:" is in the email source. The body and the header are also in the email source, but people (usually) don't read email from the source source. Instead, they prefer to have the source parsed for them by their email client.

Comment: Well, the last one i mentioned still works. [toggle-headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/thunderbird/addon/toggle-headers/?src=search). Just install it, restart and select a mail and press `H`. Now for all mails you have all the headers above the mail. Not sure if you want **all** the headers though. I haven't looked any further for one where only headers are shown according to a filter you can provide.

Comment: There used to be the [mailhops](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mailhops/) add-on but it doesn't work anymore. It was precisely what you where looking for, i think.

Answer (score 0):

## [Received](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/received) add-on

[Received](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/received) - add-on for Thunderbird, which will display the "Received from" information from the email header.